# IPFS Protocol upgrade or migrations

Tags: ipfs, swarm, protocol

How would I migrate from IPFS, let says that I got 10M files linked by IPFS, and I want to migrate all of them to Swarm, how would I do that?

The question in a different way:
I want to use a new hash function?